# geodjango returning locations in hawaii instead of la

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

My geospatial query is returning locations far away from where the latitude and longitude coordinates are.

Here is what my model looks like:

```
geometry = models.PointField(srid=4326)
geography = models.PointField(srid=3857, null= True)
```

I am trying to use the geography field so I can use meters for the distance this is what that query looks like:

```
pnt = fromstr("POINT(%s %s)" % (lat, lng), srid=3857)
Location.objects.filter(geography__dwithin=(pnt, 3500)).distance(pnt).order_by('distance')[:75]
```

Comment: Swap your (lat, lng) the other way, so it is (X, Y)

Comment: You'll need to create the point like this: `pnt = fromstr("POINT(%s %s)" % (lng, lat), srid=4326)` then transform to 3857.

Comment: do I save that point to the database then transform? this is how I was generating it in the save method in the model self.geography = fromstr("POINT(%s %s)" % (self.lng, self.lat), srid=3857)

Comment: this worked thanks jonaz!

Answer (score 0):

Just had to convert the point correctly here is the code for django:

```
pnt = fromstr("POINT(%s %s)" % (self.lng, self.lat), srid=4326)
ct = CoordTransform(SpatialReference(4326), SpatialReference(3857))
pnt.transform(ct)
```